# System verilog: define empty vector

Tags: system-verilog

In VHDL I can write `(0 downto 1)` and will generate a Vector with 0 elements.

I want to do this to "rightalign" a field in a union, if needed.
Samplecode:

```
module example #(int ITEMS=3)(output logic[4:0] result);
union {
  logic [4:0] result;
  struct {
    logic systemstatus;
    logic [4-1-ITEMS-1:0] padding;
    logic [ITEMS-1:0] itemStatus;
  } bitfield;
} myStruct;
endmodule;
```

I want to generate a struct that looks roughly like this:

```
systemstatus | 0padder | item3 | item2 | item1 //ITEMS==3
systemstatus | item4   | item3 | item2 | item1 //ITEMS==4
```

As you can see the padding field disappears for 4 items. However the code above will not do what I want in system verilog since instead of creating a vector with 0 elements, I will always create a vector with at least one element (`[0:0]`), and when the expression becomes negative (`[-1:0]]`) I will create a vector with two elements.

Is there a way to let `padding` "decay/degenerate" to an empty vector? I know I could make `myStruct.bitfield.itemStatus` simply always the right size and always access a subvector. But the point is to do the magic once in the struct and not worry about it anymore in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `let` statement instead of a `union`. The let statement is like a macro, except it is limited to a scope, and limited by substituting expressions, not any arbitrary text.

```
module example #(int ITEMS=3)(output logic[4:0] result);
  let systemstatus = result[4];
  let itemStatus = result[ITEMS-1:0];
  ...
endmodule
```

If you still want do this using a union, you can get what you want by creating your union with two structs. Also note that you need to use a packed union and struct to guarantee bit alignment.

```
union packed {
  logic [4:0] result;
  struct packed {
    logic status;
    logic [3:0] padding;
  } system;
  struct packed {
    logic [4: 1+4-ITEMS] padding;
    logic [ITEMS-1:0] status;
  } item;
} myStruct;
```

Now you can refer to `mystruct.system.status` and `mystruct.item.status`.

Comment: I actually want the union/struct bit, since i am trying o create a magic register. While the trick works if I have something infront of my padding, it does not work if there is no item infront of my padding, since padding ovelaps with result in your code.